# I need to get all keys and values inside dict that to be inside the list, but only return last key and values

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6

I need to create a price list of products using python dict. The keys and values I will receive from my users. After this price list has been created I need to get the key that contains the min values and show for my user. See my code at the moment.

I create a list to put my dicts inside and I to try to use a for loop, but only the last key and values are shown for me.

```
lista = []
for i in range(3):
  mercadoria = input("Informe o nome de um produto: ")
  preco = float(input("Informe o preço do produto: "))
  produto = {mercadoria: preco}
  lista.append(produto)

for i in lista:
  for k,v in produto.items():
    print(f"{k}:{v}")
```

I would show the values like:
a: 10
b: 5 
c: 20

You should buy the product b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `list`. Just use `dict`.
You did good to use `items()` with `for` loop.

```
produto = {}
for i in range(3):
  mercadoria = input("Informe o nome de um produto: ")
  preco = float(input("Informe o preço do produto: "))
  produto[mercadoria] = preco

for k,v in produto.items():
  print(k, v)
```

Result is:

```
Informe o nome de um produto: 1
Informe o preço do produto: 1.1
Informe o nome de um produto: 2
Informe o preço do produto: 2.2
Informe o nome de um produto: 3
Informe o preço do produto: 3.3
2 2.2
3 3.3
1 1.1
```

Comment: Thanks @yaho cho, you solutions help me!

My new code looks like this:


`from operator import itemgetter

produto = {}
for i in range(3):
  mercadoria = input("Informe o nome de um produto: ")
  preco = float(input("Informe o preço do produto: "))
  produto[mercadoria] =  preco
 
for k,v in produto.items():
  print(f"{k}:{v}")
dict_ordered = sorted(produto.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
print(f"Você deve comprar o produto {dict_ordered[0][0]} no valor de R${dict_ordered[0][1]}")`

Comment: @EricGomes Do you want to print out it in order?

Comment: no, my goal was to print all product on dict and to say for my user buy the product that had the smallest price.

Comment: @EricGomes I am sorry. You got already completed code. Great!